# IPv6 DNS Problem with archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: dns, wget, apt-mirror

Since a couple of weeks my mirror sync doesn't work as expected. I think that I identified the problem now. On my server the address archive.ubuntu.com resolves to a couple of IPv6 addresses and at least one of them doesn't seem to work for accessing the repos.
[`nslookup archive.ubuntu.com 1.1.1.1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiVJ9.png)
If wget chooses this specific address it isn't getting a response back from the webserver, that leads to a stuck sync process. If I am testing with wget, I get a response from any address for archive.ubuntu.com, except `2001:67c:1562::18`
Does this only apply to me? Is this an expected behaviour? Is it a problem with the serverside DNS configuration? Or is it just me, who is missing something obvious?

Comment: I tried `wget -6 http://[2001:67c:1562::18]` and I *did* get a response from port 80 with the contents of `index.html`.

Comment: I tested with `wget -6 --header="Host: archive.ubuntu.com" http://[2001:67c:1562::18]/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz` with the specific header to avoid problems with reverse proxys. With this I don't get a response, but if I use the address `[2001:67c:1562::15]` I get a response as expected. But `archive.ubuntu.com` resolves to both addresses.

Comment: I tried your exact command (IPv6 address ending with `:18`) and it downloaded a 2280482 byte `Packages.gz` file.

Comment: That means, this applies only to my specific setup and I need to dive deeper into troubleshooting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, there were some problems with my IPv6 routing. I needed to set my second router to do MSS Clamping, otherwise the response was received incomplete. I'm still not fully aware of what's going on but it works for now.